# Express in Rectangular Form

Tags: complex-analysis, polar-coordinates

a) $(-1+i)^{-i}$
so I know that the answer is $9.92-3.58i$. My track getting there is off.

I know that $x=-1$ and $y=1$, so $r = \sqrt{2}$, also that $\displaystyle \theta=-\frac{pi}{4}$.

I've plugged them into de Moivre's but my final answer does not match the right answer.  Help?

b) $(-1)^{1/pi}$

Answer (score 2):

Let  $-1+i=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)=r\cdot e^{i\theta}$ (Using [Euler's Identity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerFormula.html))

Equating the real & the imaginary parts

$-1=r\cos\theta, 1=r\sin\theta$

Squaring and adding we get $r^2=2\implies r=\sqrt2$

$\implies \cos\theta=-\frac1{\sqrt2}<0, \sin\theta=\frac1{\sqrt2}>0 $

From the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition) of $\arctan\frac yx,\theta= \pi+\arctan\frac1{(-1)}=\pi-\frac{\pi}4 =\frac{3\pi}4$  as the principal value of arctan lies $\in\left[-\frac\pi2, \frac\pi2\right]$

So, $$(-1+i)^i=e^{i\ln(-1+i)}=e^{i\ln(\sqrt 2e^{\frac{3\pi i}4})}$$

$$=e^{i(\frac12\ln2+\frac{3\pi i}4)}$$

$$=e^{-\frac{3\pi}4}\cdot e^{\left(i\frac{\ln 2}2\right)}$$

$$=e^{-\frac{3\pi}4}\left(\cos \frac{\ln 2}2+i\sin \frac{\ln 2}2 \right)$$

Comment: I'm not following your work. if z=re^itheta, then I have (sqrt(2)e^(i3pi/4))^-i = (sqrt(2))^-i *e^3pi/4.

Comment: @xfitpi, $\sqrt2 e^{\frac{3\pi i}4}=e^{\ln \sqrt2 e^{\frac{3\pi i}4}} $ right?

Comment: @xfitpi, more generally $a=e^{\ln a}$ and $\ln e^b=b\ln e=b$

Comment: yes, that's correct. so then my final answer in rectangular is √2e^3πi/4

Comment: @xfitpi, without calculator, yes.

Comment: what if my equation is (-1)^(1/pi).  then how do I solve for the real and imaginary parts?

Comment: As the principal value of $-1=e^{i\pi};$ So, $(-1)^\frac1{\pi}=(e^{i\pi})^\frac1{\pi}=e^i=\cos1+i\sin1$